# Node.JS IPFS ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\..\.jsipfs\blocks\LD\CI...Q.data'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

I'm trying to create an IPFS peer to peer chat app using Node.JS.

The app starts up fine and prints the swarm listening message below.

`generating Ed25519 keypair...`

`to get started, enter:`

`jsipfs cat /ipfs/QmRaaUwTNfwgFZpeUy8qrZwrp2dY4kCKmmB5xEqvH3vtD1/readme`

`Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWHhYJfffDFDLkeAhorvmtActm7YZoSn85xFATjkJ1MvVu`

`Swarm listening on /ip4/172.31.192.1/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWHhYJfffDFDLkeAhorvmtActm7YZoSn85xFATjkJ1MvVu`

However, when I try to run the command `jsipfs cat /ipfs/QmRaaUwTNfwgFZpeUy8qrZwrp2dY4kCKmmB5xEqvH3vtD1/readme`, as instructed, I get the message.

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\.jsipfs\blocks\LD\CIQDAJDJUBQWF7DOSHH3BQCDZTRVMK2ZSBADNOTKYLZHXDBMVQOMLDA.data'`

Could you please help me spot where the problem is?

Did I set the repo wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const IPFS = require('ipfs')

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

const ipfs = IPFS.create({
    repo: repo(),
    EXPERIMENTAL: {
      pubsub: true
    },
    config: {
      Addresses: {
        Swarm: [
          '/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001'
        ],
        API: "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001",
        Gateway: "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080"
      }
    }
  });

function repo () {
    return 'ipfs_' + Math.random()
}

app.listen(6500, ()=>{
    console.log('App listening on Port 6500');
});
```

Comment: Same here with 
npx jsipfs init ;
npx jsipfs pin add QmY4………
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '………/tmp/blocks/JX/CIQ